# How to copy a file to a specified path while installing exe?

Tags: c#, cmd, windows-installer, xcopy

I have to copy a file(at the time of installation) residing in same folder where `exe` and `msi installer` exist to some different path. To do this i wrote a following code in `installer` class.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new     
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "xcopy";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string SourcePath = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bin");
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\lovestone\Desktop\data.txt");
sw.WriteLine(directory);
sw.WriteLine(SourcePath);
startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + directory + "\"" + " " + "\"" + SourcePath + "\"" + @" /e /y /I";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I don't have any problem with the `installer` class because it is creating `data.txt` (at the time of installation) on the given path. How should i do copy a file from `directory` to `SourcePath`?

Should i use `cmd` instead of `xcopy`?

### Updated

As i mentioned that, i want to copy a file from the same folder where `exe` and `installer` exist. When i install my application. It shows an error:

```
Unable to find the file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\inataller".
```

It is trying to pick the file from `program files` directory. but it should be the same directory where my `exe` exist. I don't want to `hard-coded` the path for exe because it will distribute to other client. What will be the appropriate code for picking the file from same folder?

I have made some changes in code

```
string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string SourcePath = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bin");
File.Copy(Path.Combine(directory, "MyAdHocTestCert.cer"),Path.Combine(SourcePath, "MyAdHocTestCert.cer"));
```

now it is showing : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Your design is not compatible with Windows Installer at all. What exactly are you really trying to do?  Do you need to publish a certificate to the certificate store or something?  Is this just an issue of needing to transform the installation on a customer by customer basis?  There are far more elegant and robust ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Basically i need to copy my certificate file to `c:\program files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs \windows\v7.0A\Bin` at the time of installation of my exe.

Comment: Does the file name change?   Based on the tool you are using, one simple approach would be to create an Administrative Installation from your MSI and then overwrite the CER file.  Then when users install from that point it would pick up the modified file.

Comment: No file name didn't change. Actually installer are not able to pick the file from `directory` (see in the updated section code).

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I tried after setting hard-coded path in `directory` and it works :(

Comment: @Amit Pal: Did you got the solution yet?

Answer (score 5):

if you want to copy myFile.exe from your "directory" location to "SourcePath".

```
string sourceFileName = Path.Combine(directory, "myFile.exe");
string destFileName = Path.Combine(SourcePath, "myFileCopy.exe");

File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
```

The sourcefilename is simply the location of the file you want to copy and the destFileName is the destination to where you want to copy it. Including filename.

As for getting the location of the exe you can use

```
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i want to do with `cmd` using `processStartInfo`

Comment: Any specific reason for this?

Comment: No such reason.

What about the `sourceFileName` and `destfileName`? are they right according to my requirements?

Comment: @AmitPal, you would certainly have to use the `cmd` executable. You can't shell execute `xcopy`. But don't do it that way - use the method provided by Evelie.

Comment: @AmitPal Edited post with explanation of the parameters.

Comment: try the GetExecutingAssembly instead of GetEntryAssembly.

Comment: Sorry but I update  'directory' string with yours but still it is trying to find the file from 'program files' hence it shows an error

Comment: Sorry but its kinda hard telling you why it doesnt work with the given information. If you place your exe in c:\myfolder\install.exe  Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) should give you c:\myfolder\. Have you tried change GetEntryAssembly ?

Comment: I tried after setting hard-coded path in `directory` and it works :(
So, It means the problem resides in picking file from same directory

Comment: Application.StartupPath; how about this one?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring what you've done so far,  create a new installer and author the certificate file into it like normal.  Build the MSI and run the command:

```
msiexec /a foo.msi TARGETDIR=C:\EXTRACT /qb
```

Now take a look at C:\EXTRACT. You'll see an uncompressed MSI and a directory structure of files.  Overwrite the CER file with the file you want to deploy.  Now run that MSI on a machine and note which CER file was deployed.

It really should be that simple.  If you were using a better tool such as InstallShield or WiX you could build a partly compressed MSI and uncompressed single file.  There's no need for all these horrible custom action anti-patterns where MSI call's DLL call's CMD call's XCOPY.   BTW, you do know VDPROJ was removed from VS2012, right?